# Logistic Regression in PyMC

Tags: python-2.7, statistics, pymc

Something of a beginner question, but I'm coming from different languages, and can't find quite the right example. I'm trying to set up a simple logistic regression in PyMC 2. Consider a `pandas` data frame "Data" with a layout something like this:

```
ID, GotSick, Salad, Sandwich, Water
1,0,0,1,0
2,1,1,0,1
3,0,1,0,0
....
100,1,1,0,1
```

I'm trying to find the odds ratios of "Salad", "Sandwich" and "Water" on the outcome "GotSick". In R, I'd set it up something like:

```
model <- glm(GotSick ~ Salad + Sandwich + Water, data=Data, family="binomial")
```

But it's not fully clear to me how to set up the model in PyMC.

```
### hyperpriors
tau = mc.Gamma('tau', 1.e-3, 1.e-3, value=10.)
sigma = mc.Lambda('sigma', lambda tau=tau: tau**-.5)

### parameters
# fixed effects
beta0 =  mc.Normal('beta0',  0., 1e-6, value=0.)
betaSalad =  mc.Normal('betaSalad',  0., 1e-6, value=0.) 
betaSandwich =  mc.Normal('betaSandwich',  0., 1e-6, value=0.)
betaWater = mc.Normal('betaWater',  0., 1e-6, value=0.)

# expected parameter
logit_p =  (beta0 + betaSalad*x1 + betaSandwich*x2 + betaWater*x3)
```

Where I've run aground is the @mc.observed stage - any pointers?

Comment: I believe `pymc3` support `GLM` module. You can find an example [here](http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2013/09/12/bayesian-glms-1/).

Comment: Why do you define tau and sigma? Near as I can tell they are not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track.  I'm not solving your homework problem am I?  It is now a preferred idiom to `import pymc as pm` instead of `mc`, so to finish this up with an `observed` decorator, just use:

```
import pymc as pm

@pm.observed
def y(logit_p=logit_p, value=df.GotSick):
    return pm.bernoulli_like(df.GotSick, pm.invlogit(logit_p))
```

Here is [a notebook that puts this in all together](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/8329ec1b9f861469f896).

Comment: I am far too old for this to be homework. This is, instead, trying to support migrating fully to Python from an unholy mix of Python, R and SAS.